# What methods does the built-in join function use?

Tags: python, built-in

I'm trying to use

```
a = ''.join((Symbol('a'), Symbol('b'))
```

but I get

```
File "/home/j/_Github-Projects/MiscScripts/string_permutations.py", line 72, in get_permutations
    permutation = Symbol(''.join(permutation))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Symbol found
```

The python docs says an iterable is accepted as the parameter for `join` but that seems to contradict what the exception is telling me.

I tried defining some of the base class methods in `Symbol` but it didn't help.

```
def __concat__(self, other):
    return Symbol(self.symbol + other.symbol)
__add__ = __concat__
__and__ = __concat__

def __iconcat__(self, other):
    self.symbol += other.symbol
    return self
```

[str.join(iterable) docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: It doesn't matter which methods it uses because it only accepts strings, not `Symbol`s. You have to create a list of strings from those Symbols if you want to use `join`.

Comment: It explicitly days right there in the docs that only iterables with all strings will work...

Comment: *”that seems to contradict what the exception is telling me”* - no, it doesn’t. The exception is telling you that the types of the things *inside the iterable* are the problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but why don't they change the parameter name from `iterable` to `string` if only strings are accepted?

Comment: Because the parameter doesn’t have to be a string (which is itself an iterable of strings: the characters), but could be *any iterable of strings* (e.g. a list, tuple, generator, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) also says:

> A TypeError will be raised if there are any non-string values in
>   iterable...

And after all, `Symbol('a')` is not a String.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this should do it, not `join`.

```
        permutation = functools.reduce(
            lambda x, y: x.concatenate(y),
            permutation)
```

The joys of a dynamic language, glance at parameter name, but not realize that only certain value types are accepted.